# Issue with getting parameter and use it in fopen() in C

Tags: c

I have trouble understanding why I do not get any output here. I've tested without a function and added it to the main function with luck.

I want to iterate the text file line by line and display it. I want to use the function `printlines()` to take a string/char parameter so that I can open it by the `fopen()` function.

**Here's my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printlines(const char *fname)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");

    int c;
    while ((c == fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }   

    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    printlines("urls.txt"); 
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get any error messages in GCC. I compile like this:

```
gcc main.c -o main -g
```

Comment: Mybe the `urls.txt` file does not exist. Also check if  `fopen` returns `NULL`.

Comment: As you compile with  `-g` already: How does this look like when tracing the code using the GDB debugger?

Comment: .... and it's `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` not `while ((c == fgetc(fp)) != EOF)`

Comment: Where is your check of the `return` from `fopen`??

Comment: Good point @DavidC.Rankin, I will add that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while ((c == fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` does no assignment.  `==` should be replaced by `=` there.

Comment: Embarrassing that I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the conditional/assignment issue, when you are learning C (or any language) validate each required step. When you call `printlines` you have absolutely no way to know whether it succeeded or failed. (yes, you either get output or your don't, but that is well after the failure should have been caught and handled) Further, within `printlines` you start reading from the stream before you know if it is a valid open stream. You can protect against both with simple validations. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printlines(const char *fname)
{
    int c;
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (!fp)  /* validate file open, or return fail */
        return 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }   

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* valdate successful return, or throw error */
    if (!printlines(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "urls.txt")) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "urls.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, by providing a simple integer return from `printlines` after validating `fopen`, you give yourself the ability to handle an open failure (back in the calling function) in the event a bad filename is passed. **[1]**

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/validatefopen
error: file open failed 'urls.txt'.

$ ./bin/validatefopen ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

You should get in the habit of validating each step in your code where subsequent operation depends on successful completion of that step, or where any user input is involved.

**footnotes:**

**[1.]** that is also why a `FILE *` pointer is generally passed as a parameter to output routines rather than the filename. e.g. `void printlines (FILE *fp)` -- so the stream can be validated in the caller before the print routine is called.

**Passing FILE* to printlines**

As mentioned above, a more traditional approach (on several levels) would be to validate the open stream in the calling function (`main` here) before calling `printlines`. Additionally, rather than utilizing the *ternary* operator as the parameter for `printlines`, it allows assignment of the filename (either provided as the first argument to the program or `urls.txt` by default) outside the parameter list.

The *ternary* operator being similar to shorthand for `if... else...` in the form `test ? if true code : if false code` allows for using the first parameter as the filename while defaulting to `urls.txt` if none is given with `const char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "urls.txt";`. Where `argc > 1` is the *test*, `argv[1]` the *if true code* and `"urls.txt"` the string-literal used as the *if false code*. Compare both, and let me know if you have further questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printlines (FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "urls.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        return 1;
    }

    printlines (fp);

    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great info David. Shouldn't be returning 1 instead of 0 if the validation of the file opening is failing?

Comment: It's up to you. I wanted the criteria in `main` to be `if (!printlines...` in that case it must return a `0` on fail. The only general `0/1` rule is you return `0` to the *shell* on success. The rest of the internal returns are up to you `:)`

Comment: Alright :) Really appreciated this answer. Thanks David!

Comment: `if (!printlines(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "urls.txt")) {` legit code and does the job. Yet a more classic coding is suggested.

Comment: Grumble... Agreed, will add a more traditional example `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should also check to see if the file has been opened for reading

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
    return;
}
```